# Laravel: Single Data is not showing: Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have a Modal to show details of Data with this below link:

```
<a onclick="showProductPricing({{ $customer->id }})">Show</a>
```

showProductPricing function in ajax:

```
showProductPricing = function (customerId) {

    save_method = 'show';

    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ url('admin/singleProductPricing') }}" + '/' + customerId,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#showproductPricing').modal('show');
            $('#productName').val(data.productName);
            $('#productPrice').val(data.productPrice);
        },

        error: function (data) {
            console.log((data));
        }
    });
};
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/admin/singleProductPricing/{id}','ProductPriceController@singleProductPrice');
```

Controller:

```
public function singleProductPrice($id)
{
     $singleProductPrice = ProductPricing::find($id);
     return $singleProductPrice;
}
```

Blade: 
I am using Data Table. Which is a Modal. But in modal data is not coming. No info also in `console.log`

```
<tr>
   <td><span class="text-danger" id="productName"></span></td>
   <td><span class="text-danger" id="productPrice"></span></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hey, just to remind you the big blue button you pushed has something witting on it which is not present in this page

Comment: I can't understand what you have told.

Comment: where is your question?

Comment: Larvel: Single Data is not showing: Ajax

Answer (score 0):

Try following code;

```
$('#productName').text(data.productName);
$('#productPrice').text(data.productPrice);
```

Instead of;

```
$('#productName').val(data.productName);
$('#productPrice').val(data.productPrice);
```

Comment: Please first, please find out source of it problem.

Did you check all parameters?
data parameter is return as successful to the ajax success method from laravel action?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that the # id must be unique throughout the page

I have implemented the above feature like the below code:

```
 function editData(id) {

    var url = APP_URL + '/languages/' + id + '/edit' ;
    $.get(url , function (data) {
        var data =data.ResponseMessage;
        $('#Id').val(data.LanguageId);
        $('#Name').val(data.Name);
        $('#IsActive').prop('checked',true).iCheck('update');
        $('#editModal').modal('show');
    }) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first, assign the value to related #id and interchange the position like the display at below :

```
  $('#productName').val(data.productName);
  $('#productPrice').val(data.productPrice);
  $('#showproductPricing').modal('show');
```